# syntax error unexpected T_ENCAPSED... php

Tags: php, mysql

Probably a really simple one to do with quotes but php is not my thing!

```
"INSERT INTO feedback_test (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')"
```

getting the error unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: Forgot a semi-colon? `;`

Comment: Learn to use PDO and prepared statements!

Comment: that is not valid php. There should be stuff above it. and below it. and a `;`. this is too short a sample to find out what your problem is. Show us the smallest example that gives you the error, not just this part (note the "smallest" part!)

Comment: better post the whole codes, we arent a magician somehow..

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO feedback_test (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES
('".$_POST["firstname"]."','".$_POST["lastname"]."','".$_POST["age"]."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, every statement ends with a semocolon.

So add a semocolon (`;`) to your line.

Again, you are not adding single quotes (`'`) to your posted values.

So, in total, update your query to:

```
"INSERT INTO feedback_test (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES
('$_POST[\'firstname\']','$_POST[\'lastname\']','$_POST[\'age\']')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't give index of `$_POST` with quote. if index of `$_POST` is string then it must be give with puote.

just try this

```
"INSERT INTO `feedback_test` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age`) VALUES
('".$_POST['firstname']."','".$_POST['lastname']."','".$_POST['age']."')"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO feedback_test (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('".$_POST['firstname']."','".$_POST['lastname']."','".$_POST['age']."')";
```

Comment: Also you should add quote as `$_POST["firstname"]` otherwise error will occur.